# How to convert a huge ASF audio file to OGG (or MP3) under Linux?

Tags: linux, audio

I have a huge ASF audio file, about 10 hours long. I want to convert it to MP3 or OGG. I use Linux. I tried to convert it to WAV first (using `mplayer -ao pcm`), but I got a message that this file is too long for WAV.

What method do you advise?

Comment: I've removed the answer suggesting LAME since it was entirely copypasted from an external resource without attribution. If LAME failed for you, please [edit] your question to give us some new info about what went wrong. Thanks!